# Complex Rule Evaluation Logic in Apex

Tags: apex

I am tasked with writing apex alogrithm that needs to evaluate records against a set of 100 rules. The rules condition can be something like:

```
Contact.Geo = US AND (
   Contact.Communication_Preferences__c CONTAINS Email OR 
   Contact.Communication_Preferences__c CONTAINS SMS) 
                 AND 
   Contact.Account.Level__c EQUALS Platinum
```

The rule, if the rule condition is met, will provide next steps directions (post processing, which we can ignore for this question)

There would be 100 such rules and the conditions can be fairly complex containing multiple fields joined by AND/OR operators and parenthesis.

Can anyone help with best practices for this implementation keeping performance in mind. We are open to do this via batch jobs, but we want the most optimized approach so that it takes min time.

Comment: You need to look up Apex rules engines or callable 3rd party rules engines.

Comment: Also [Business Rules Engine](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.business_rules_engine.htm&type=5).

Comment: @cropredy - thanks for the answer..doing fit-gap analysis

Comment: @DavidCheng - thanks for the answer..would you have any remote idea around costing?

Comment: You'll have to check with your Salesforce account executive.